# How to change from DateTime in Django model to Date only

Tags: datetime

Hi have the following field in a model:
fee_payment_1_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

I now realise that I don't need the time element, and I want to change my model to just
fee_payment_1_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

Is it likely to be a straight forward migration process? I already have a lot of data collected.